# Есть ли погрешность при работе с большими числами в python?

Tags: python, rsa

Реализую алгоритм шифрования `rsa`. Шифрую сообщение следующим образом

```
for i in range(len(dig_text)):
    dig_text[i] = (dig_text[i]**e) % n
```

Расшифровываю:

```
for i in range(len(crypt)):
    crypt[i] = pow(crypt[i], d) % n
```

Проблема в расшифровке. Для небольших чисел вычисляется корректный результат, но с большими числами `d` и `n` результат некорректный.
Есть предположения, что при больших `e`, `d` и `n` теряется точность вычислений. Если проблема в этом, то как её решить? А если не в этом, то в чем тогда?

Comment: Покажите достаточно полный код, демонстрирующий проблему. По таким вырванным из контекста кусочкам ничего дельного сказать нельзя

Comment: Укажите размеры чисел в байтах. Также проверьте типы данных, до шифрования и после.

Comment: А что за числа то, какого типа? Если `float`, то да - будут ошибки, `float` не способен точно представлять любые числа. Есть варианты, как обойти, но дайте больше деталей.

Comment: И непонятно, почему в одном месте вы используете `**`, а в другом `pow` - это чтобы ещё больше запутаться?

Answer (score 3):

У встроенной функции `pow` есть третий аргумент как-раз для вашего случая. Попробуйте использовать вместо ваших конструкций такие:

- `(dig_text[i]**e)%n` --> `pow(dig_text[i], e, n)`
- `pow(crypt[i],d) % n` --> `pow(crypt[i], d, n)`

[Пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59143871/8324991), что такой вариант работает гораздо быстрее и эффективнее для больших чисел (для маленьких чисел всё наоборот).

Но вообще, если вы используете целочисленные данные и встроенную функцию `pow`, а не `math.pow`, то проблем с округлением/представлением чисел быть не должно - `int` в питоне не ограничен. А вот `math.pow` всегда использует  тип `float`, имеющий ограниченную точность, поэтому у него такие проблемы могут быть.

Если же вам нужны обязательно вычисления с плавающей точкой, то можно посмотреть в сторону более точного представления чисел `numpy.float128` а лучше на числа с плавающей точкой без потери точности `decimal.Decimal`.